# FaceBook FQL issue while extracting album name in Iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I have 3 albums in my Face Book account.

1. profile
2. NaturePhoto
3. Profile Pictures

when i use below FQL Query the  `"request:didLoad:"` delegate return the empty array.

```
 NSString* fql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT cover_pid,name FROM album WHERE owner == %lld", session.uid]; 

NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];

[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
```

I am really struck in Face book FQL.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `=` not `==`

A query for the current authenticated user would be

```
 SELECT cover_pid,name FROM album WHERE owner = me()
```

Which returns a correct response